# Why does Rails use plurals for new and create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pluralize

I understand why a Rails `index` method would use the plural form of a resource - we're showing all `projects`, for example.

And I understand why the `show` method would use the singular form - we only want to see one `project`, with a particular ID.

But I don't understand why `new` and `create` would use the plural. Is there a way to create more than one `project` at a time? Is there some other reasoning for using the plural here that someone could explain?

Comment: are you talking about the routing conventions? like http://whatever.com/books/new ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New and Create aren't plural, in the way I think about REST. Instead, I think about it like:

`whatever.com` is your base domain, and `whatever.com/books` means that you have a collection of resources each named book. The collection itself is named books.

So, when you want to create a new book, you are asking the collection for the information needed to create a new book. This becomes `/books/new`

When you actually create the book, you are posting information to `/books`. The HTTP verb is POST, so when you POST to your collection, you execute the create action.

This looks like a [good starting point](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2008/02/04/restful-rails-part-i/) on REST.

Comment: Thanks. It still feels to me like I would want to say `/book/new` when creating one book. It's not a big deal, but since the whole purpose of pluralization is to make things more like plain English, it's odd to have to say something that feels like "I want to create a new books" instead of "a new book."

Comment: reading /book for me automatically mewns that i'm refering some specific already existing book therefore /book/new doesn't make sense from that point of view and /books/new makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1):

I thought they were always plural. Scroll down a bit on [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for an example of the routes generated by `resources :photos`

Whether you're GETting a single resource or POSTing to the collection, you're still in the domain of `photos`. So, search the domain of `photos` given an id, POST a new photo to the domain of `photos`, etc.